# how to test function inside another function using jest and typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I have to test processMsg. But, it is not getting called. following is the code I tried:

userdata.ts

```
import { listen } from './rdkafka';
export class UserData {
    unsubscribe: any;
    config: any;

    constructor() {
        this.config = {
           name: 'msgHandler'
        }
    };
    private processMsg = (value): void => {
        console.log('param value', value.toString());
        this.unsubscribe();
    };
    getData = (): void => {
        this.unsubscribe = listen({
            name: this.config.name,
            processMessage: this.processMsg
        });
    };
}
```

test.ts

```
describe('UserData', () => {
    let userData: UserData;
    beforeEach(() => {
        userData = new UserData();
    });
    it('userData', () => {
        expect(userData.getData()).toBeUndefined();
    })
})
```

listen.ts

```
const listen = ({name, processMessage}) => {
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

    socket.addEventListener('message', async (data) => {
        await processMessage(data)
    });
}
```

getData method is tested successfully, but need to test listen method inside getData. Any help in this will be really helpful

Comment: Can you add more context to the question please? for listen function where it comes from?

Comment: code added for listen method also. @MehdiBelbal

Comment: You shouldn't test `listen` in your `UserData` tests. You should only check if it is called with the right parameters.
Look a this link to mock `listen`: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules

Comment: Then in that case, the private method will never gonna test because it is getting called from inside of listen. then, the coverage will not be 100%.

Testing a private method is also not a good practice to directly, because it is in a flow with other method, Please correct me if I am wrong. @known-as-bmf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) mock `./rdkafka` module, `listen` function, and its implementation. Then you can get the original private method `processMsg` in the test case according to the object passed into `listen` function. After this, you can test `processMsg` method. Below is the unit test solution:

E.g.

`userdata.ts`:

```js
import { listen } from './rdkafka';

export class UserData {
  unsubscribe: any;
  config: any;

  constructor() {
    this.config = {
      name: 'msgHandler',
    };
  }
  private processMsg = (value): void => {
    console.log('param value', value.toString());
    this.unsubscribe();
  };
  getData = (): void => {
    this.unsubscribe = listen({
      name: this.config.name,
      processMessage: this.processMsg,
    });
  };
}
```

`rdkafka.ts`:

```js
export const listen = (opts) => {
  console.log('real implementation');
};
```

`userdata.test.ts`:

```js
import { UserData } from './userdata';
import { listen } from './rdkafka';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';

jest.mock('./rdkafka');

describe('63123784', () => {
  let userData: UserData;
  beforeEach(() => {
    userData = new UserData();
  });
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(listen)).toBeTruthy();
    expect(userData.getData()).toBeUndefined();
  });
  it('should process message', () => {
    let processMessageRef;
    const mUnsubscribe = jest.fn();
    mocked(listen).mockImplementationOnce((opts) => {
      processMessageRef = opts.processMessage;
      return mUnsubscribe;
    });
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    userData.getData();
    processMessageRef(1);
    expect(listen).toBeCalledWith({ name: 'msgHandler', processMessage: processMessageRef });
    expect(mUnsubscribe).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('param value', '1');
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/63123784/userdata.test.ts (9.673s)
  63123784
    ✓ should pass (3ms)
    ✓ should process message (26ms)

  console.log
    param value 1

      at CustomConsole.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866:25)

-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files    |   92.31 |      100 |      80 |   91.67 |                   
 rdkafka.ts  |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 2                 
 userdata.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.946s
```